# Assign variable in Mac .bashrc to play afplay 'sound/path.mp3'

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have a series of sound clips, I want to assign them to a variable in my *.bashrc* to play specific sound clips.

I know I can do `afplay "sound/path.mp3"` to that directory, but I would like something simpler.

If I could call `$WHAT` in terminal for instance and it played Lil Jon's '*WHHATT!*'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I'd say you could put something like this in your .bashrc:

```
what2()
{
    /path/to/afplay "/path/to/my.mp3"
}
```

which will allow you to have a command 'what2' available on the command-line.

Comment: There is a "what" system cmd existing that could be masked with this, but otherwise a simple solution.

Comment: @drclaw Never knew there is such a system command. Changed my answer into 'what2', thanks.